# Using sys.diana and sys.pidl to parse PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, parse

It seems to me that it should be possible to parse existing PL/SQL with the packages  `sys.diana` and `sys.pidl`, but I have found nothing on the internet with the exception of a few scripts that seem to unwrap a wrapped package (and that is useless for my purposes).

So, does anyone know about a pointer into the right direction?

Comment: Like you, I've only heard of the concept in regards to reverse-engineering a wrapped package. In that line, maybe a post to Pete Finnigan's security forum might find someone who has done some work in that area.

Comment: What is your goal in parsing the PL/SQL?

Comment: I have no specific goal in mind, I just thought it'd be nice to be able to read an already parsed syntax tree. It might be handy at some time in the future for something I don't no yet.

Comment: better late than never, found this presentation about reverse engineering pl/sql. http://www.petefinnigan.com/UnwrappingPLSQLBlackHat2006.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The [official documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/e_limits.htm) covering unusual errors describes DIANA:
PL/SQL is based on the programming language Ada. As a result, PL/SQL uses a variant of Descriptive Intermediate Attributed Notation for Ada (DIANA), a tree-structured intermediate language. It is defined using a meta-notation called Interface Definition Language (IDL). DIANA is used internally by compilers and other tools.

At compile time, PL/SQL source code is translated into machine-readable m-code. Both the DIANA and m-code for a procedure or package are stored in the database. At run time, they are loaded into the shared memory pool. The DIANA is used to compile dependent procedures; the m-code is simply executed.

I see why you are interested.  Access to the compiler underlying PL/SQL is tantalizing if you like looking under the hood.  Nonetheless I would be reluctant to invest a lot of time
when the same goal can be accomplished by parsing with PL/SQL.

As someone who has used your site many times I can only thank you for having an inquiring mind.